# Python Selenium Automatic Redirection Problem

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver, webautomation

I am facing issues while scraping https://www.mca.gov.in/content/mca/global/en/home.html.

Whenever I try to open this in selenium or undetectedchromedriver, it automatically redirects to its home page, while there is no problem if I do it with normal browser.

I tried multiple solution like disabling anchor tags but nothing worked. I just want to stay on the site, I already found the way to solve the captcha.

This is the code I have been running and testing multiple ways:

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
import time

driver = uc.Chrome()

driver.get("https://www.mca.gov.in/content/mca/global/en/mca/master-data/MDS.html")

time.sleep(10)

driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell exactly what's going on, but some general tips:

- Are you running your Chrome drive in headless mode? Some websites are able to detect this. For example if you go to [this website](https://arh.antoinevastel.com/bots/areyouheadless) with a headless browser you will see that it detects the browser as being headless. **A solution could therefore be to scrape the website with a headful browser**
- You could also try to use a [web scraping API](https://scraperbox.com) that does all the heavy lifting for you. But those are not free.